# List currently logged in users of an account in php using active sessions

Tags: php, session, session-state

I'd like to implement the ability for users of an account to view all currently logged in users (active sessions) in **php**. We are storing sessions in memcached and store the following data:

```
$_SESSION['account_id'] = 'act_KFrNGynOAlyHJfA4w0xq';
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 'usr_H4Jwm9VyppgSsT4dsEfM';
$_SESSION['log_in_timestamp'] = time();
```

What is not clear, is how can I get all active user sessions for a given account from memcached? As I understand it, the ssid are random and not organized in any fashion.

Comment: You can't. Even if you could, you won't be able to freely switch between sessions to see, which user the session is associated with. You can only switch to another session before headers have been sent, that is, before first output.

Answer (score 2):

The SSID are random as far as I know and I would avoid trying to identify sessions like that.

Instead, I would store separately the TIMESTAMP of the last request for every user (when was each user last seen).

Then, to display the list of active users, you would select only the users that have requests recently (they were seen recently), e.g. in the last 30 seconds.

If storing that data in the database doesn't work for you, you can find a way to cache the data.

Comment: That is one approach, but I was hoping to allow users to kill logged in sessions as well, which requires knowing the SSID right?

Comment: I think killing the session of specific user is a bit of a different problem. I would again not try to change the sessions, but add an extra verification step for each request and see if the user was forced or not to log out. Do you think that would work for your project?